# write methods on model or pass model as parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, modal-dialog, class-method

Can someone explain how to determine whether methods which work on an instance of a modal class should be defined on the modal or seperately with the modal instance be passed in as a parameter?

Here is an example:

I have a modal called `Visitor` and `Marketing`. I need to define a method `start_marketing` and `stop_marketing`.

**I can create them in the visitor modal like this:**

```
  class Visitor < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :marketing

    def start_marketing(options)
      # massage the passed in attribute here
      # then make api calls
      # then do some business logic here
      self.marketing.create options
    end

    def stop_marketing(options)
      # massage the passed in attribute here
      # then make api calls
      # then do some business logic here
      marketing = self.marketing.find options
      marketing.update_attributes {:mark_stopped => true}
    end
  end
```

**Or I can create them in the marketing modal like this:**

```
  class Marketing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :visitor

    def self.start(visitor, options)
      # massage the passed in attribute here
      # then make api calls
      # then do some business logic here
      Marketing.create {:visitor_id => visitor.id}.merge(options)

    end

    def self.stop(visitor,options)
      # massage the passed in attribute here
      # then make api calls
      # then do some business logic here
      marketing.find_by_visitor_id_and_id options[:id], options[:visitor_id]
      marketing.update_attributes {:mark_stopped => true}
    end
  end
```

These are just example to highlight the point I am confused on. In reality these methods would do more things on the instance besides just updating a record.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question. The first version is more the rails way.  For one thing you are using the  built-in association methods and avoiding passing ids around in as in your second example.

I can't provide a definitive answer without more detail regarding the exact problem you are having.

Comment: what do you think about way too many methods in the `visitor` modal when going with the first approach. In the first approach, the stuff, i.e. creation of records is happening on the `marketing` modal, but the methods are added on the `visitor` modal. This will make the `visitor` modal fat very quickly. Your comments?